# localhost vs live server for app admin panel

Tags: php, localhost, hosting, web-hosting

I have my ebook reading flutter application and its admin panel is written in PHP script.
all I wanted to know is what will be the difference if I host my admin panel to localhost rather than using a live server as the admin panel is only for storing user data and uploading books.
so can I use localhost for the admin panel??

Comment: This really needs more focus. Its off-topic here, either way, however, do you intend for people to access it out-side of your loopback interface? If so, you should bind it to your LAN interface. Then, do you intend for people to access it over the WWAN? Then you need to expose the service, typically yes... through a server.

Comment: localhost is generally used for development and testing locally, before you publish the application to a server for real use. That way, you've got an environment on your machine which you can use to develop and test new features, without interfering with the current operation of the live system. Each environment (localhost and server) will contain a separate copy of the application, database, and any other components required by the software. More sophisticated / larger applications in bigger organisations often have multiple such non-live environments (dev, test, UAT, training etc) if needed.